# Modify existing woo-commerce website design with new structure

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, e-commerce, woocommerce-theming

Can we change the existing woo-commerce UI design with new structure keeping old data of the website? We have a woo-commerce website that is using an inbuilt theme. We have used child theme for its customization, but now we have to completely change its structure, keeping old data and payment things same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a consulting/design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We however can can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "Yes. You can change the existing woo-commerce UI design with new struture keeping old data of the website". Just create new theme for the woocommerce files. A very simple google search in this area would have given you this link to theming woocommerce pages: https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/